# Cannot GET /parse/functions/

Tags: nginx, parse-server

I am quite new to maintaining Parse, but already I am about to go insane ;)

We have a parse server setup on a debian machine. It runs nginx and uses pm2 for the deployment of Parse.
Parse-Dashboard is working well, even our parse server is popping up there with its mongodb. However, the server doesn't seem to work for us. We can access `domain.com/parse/serverinfo` and e.g. `domain.com/parse/users`, which will show us the correct user list. 
However, calling any of our functions from our cloud code is out of the question... it doesn't work.

I have been googling and googling this issue over and over, and the most I can seem to find is people having the `mount` parameter in their `index.js` incorrectly configured. However, that is not the case for us.

This is our index.js:

```
// Example express application adding the parse-server module to expose Parse
// compatible API routes.

var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');
var S3Adapter = require('parse-server').S3Adapter;

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
    console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var protocol = process.env.HTTPS ? 'https://' : 'http://';
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://****:****@api.domain.com:27017/parse' || 'mo$
    cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    appId: process.env.APP_ID || '*****',
    masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '*****', //Add your master$
    fileKey: process.env.FILE_KEY || '*****',
    serverURL: 'http://api.domain.com:' + port + '/parse' || process.env.SERVER_URL || protocol + $
    liveQuery: {
        classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"]
    },
    publicServerURL: 'http://api.domain.com:' + port + '/parse',
    filesAdapter: new S3Adapter(
        "*****",
        "/*****/*****",
        "*****", {
            directAccess: true
        }
    )
});

var app = express();
var publicServerURL = "http://api.domain.com:1337/parse";

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

console.log("Mounth path: " + process.env.PARSE_MOUNT);

var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).send('I dream of being a website.  Please star the parse-server repo on GitHub!');
});

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
});

console.log('serverUrl configured as', protocol + 'localhost:' + port + '/parse');

var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

The Nginx config is:

```
# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS - serve HTML from /usr/share/nginx/html, proxy requests to /parse/
# through to Parse Server
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name api.domain.com;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/api.domain.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/api.domain.com.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        # Pass requests for /parse/ to Parse Server instance at localhost:1337
        location /parse/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/parse/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /dashboard/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://00.000.00.000:4040/dashboard/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

I cannot figure out what it is that we have incorrect in our config, and why `parse/users` and `parse/serverinfo` *does* work

Answer (score 3):

parse-server does [not handle **GET**](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/src/Routers/FunctionsRouter.js#L35) for `/functions`. Instead you can call all your cloud functions pre-defined in your cloud code file via **POST** against `/functions/your_function_name`. You can find more details about cloud code [here](http://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-functions) .

Most of the SDKs provide a mechanism to interact with cloud code that handles this for you. Depending on which sdk you're using (or REST directly) you can check out the [docs](http://docs.parseplatform.org) for more details.